# How can i build a character that is blind but has an alternate way of sight?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I was talking with my DM recently and i thought about building a character that is blind but does not relie on tremor-sense. Could i make a character that is blind but uses say a type of Magical Sight to see in 4th edition? 
Are there any rules for effects like this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. I've explored a similar idea; you might find the answers to [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19126/4398) helpful. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: This needs more information. In what way would the Magical sight be different to regular sight? A character who is blind but can see would mechanically just be a character who can see and roleplay-wise would see differently.

Comment: Some details that would be useful to add: What about tremorsense makes it inappropriate? In what ways do you want magical sight to be different from mundane sight? Do you want blindness to be overall a negative thing which magical sight partially mitigates, or do you want magical sight to be useful enough that blindness isn't really a problem? Also, I'm not familiar with "Arcanic Sight" and can't find any reference to it in the 4e online Compendium, so explaining that would be helpful, too.

Comment: If you'd like to [come into chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) we can help you workshop this question.

Comment: We need more information. We don't need to know exactly how this "magical sight" works, but we do need to know what the character "sees". Does he see light, or heat, or brainwaves, or some other form of radiation? Or does he see something else entirely? If he sees light, what makes his blindness different from traditional sight? Can he tell the difference between shades of light and darkness? Does he see colors, and if so, do they match what "normal" vision sees? Another problem to tackle is reading. Could the character read words printed on a page, where the only real difference is the color

Comment: I honestly feel this should be a fluff option and not a mechanical one, 4e will not be you friend if you are blind, even with alternative vision because your options will be extremely limited as a player.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, there's no mechanical or rules-based method of building a blind character. That said, I did this in a 3.5e game several years ago, and the steps my DM and I took to make the character work might be useful to you. None of these tricks are edition-specific; they rely on good communication and agreement between you and your DM, as well as simple houserules and a lot of roleplaying.

My character was a psion (telepath), who had lost her sight due to illness. I worked with my DM to answer a bunch of fundamental questions in a way that was neither crippling to me as a character, nor overpowered. These questions included things like, was I affected by gaze attacks? what was my speed? How did abilities which rely on sight affect me? ...etc.

We also created a houserule in order to allow the character to be functional in the party without having the whole campaign centered around her blindness. It worked roughly as follows: My character, as a psion, could "see" minds around her such that she was aware of roughly where other creatures were relative to her own position, to allow her to target attacks in combat without the usual blindness penalty. IIRC its range was five or six squares, and it did not allow her to see objects or mindless creatures like spiders (which can make for interesting combats). If you wanted to adapt this to your character, he might be able to sense the arcane energies of living beings.

Outside of combat, we had an NPC companion character (in the story, he was the healer assigned to my character's care) who stayed with her and guided her to make sure she didn't run into things. At high levels, as abilities like blindsight and tremorsense became available to her, he was less necessary, but at low levels he was extremely helpful and made the whole blindness thing more believable within the story.

These worked well together to allow my character to have the feeling of being blind in a world which largely depends on sight, but without making her a burden on the party.

Answer (score 9):

In the spirit of 4th Edition, it would be easy to simply say that the character is blind, but sees echoes of the Feywild/Shadowfell on the world with no real mechanical changes.

If you'd really like to work up a working mechanical change, you could look to the [Miraluka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Miraluka) of Star Wars. Their [Force Sight](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_sight) would work quite well for what you're trying to do, with only minor retooling for 4th Edition:

Assuming your DM doesn't want it to be free, you'd have to decide whether it would be a feat, racial ability replacement, or possibly even a new skill. It sounds, though, like you're not looking for a mechanical advantage ("I'm immune to gaze attacks!"), but rather a flavor option. If anything, ask to spend a skill training on a specialized form of Perception, and use it just as you would normal sight.

Comment: Retooling in what ways?

Comment: Assuming your DM doesn't want it to be free, you'd have to decide whether it would be a feat, racial ability replacement, or possibly even a new skill. It sounds, though, like you're not looking for a mechanical advantage ("I'm immune to gaze attacks!"), but rather a flavor option. Edit - If anything, ask to spend a skill training on a specialized form of Perception, and use it just as you would normal sight.